# What is a Māraka daśās (मारक दशा)? Is Saturn considered to be the perfect amongst the Māraka planets?

Tags: astrology, navagraha, shani, brihaspati

So many times in the TV Astrology programs, I have heard the term 'Māraka daśās' being used.

Sometimes back, one priest also calculated and diagnosed me with one of the Māraka daśās of Guru (Jupiter), and recommended some remedies.

Now, several times during these discussions, I have come across two contrasting phrases in regards to the Māraka daśās from astrologers, both personally, on tv or in online resources -

> 1. Shani graha is said to exhibit with the ability to inflict a perfect Māraka daśā on the 'jâtaka'.

- That means if one is afflicted with a perfect Māraka daśa from Shani, then they are sure to experience the full effect of it, and nothing can save them.

In contrast to the above statement,

> 2. Although, Shani is said to exhibit perfect Māraka daśā, yet it can remedied with appropriate remedies. However, if by chance, if Guru is exhibiting a perfect Māraka daśā on the native, then noone is capable of saving such person from the afflictions which shall follow.

- The implications in this case being: for once the Māraka daśās of Shani maybe mitigated, however in case of Guru, there's no mitigation if Guru is inflicting its perfect Māraka daśā on the native.

### Question:

1. How does jyotiṣa-śāstras define the term 'Māraka daśās'?
2. Can any truth be attached with the above two statements? Does any canonical text dwell on the perfect inflicting nature of either a Saturn's or Guru's Māraka daśā? And which one amongst them are considered more destructive, astrologically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Question 1. How does jyotiṣa-śāstras define the term 'Māraka daśās'?`

Chapter 44, of the Brihat-Parashara-Hora-Shastra, deals with the concepts of the Māraka.

> [Chapter 44](https://archive.org/details/BPHSEnglish/BPHS%20-%201%20RSanthanam/page/n437/mode/2up?view=theater), Māraka (Killer) Planets
>
> अथ मारकभेदाध्यायः ॥ ४४ ॥
>
> तृतीयमष्टमस्थानमायुःस्थानां द्वयं द्विज । मारकं तद्व्ययस्थानं द्वितीयं
> सप्तमं तथा ॥ २॥ तत्रापि सप्तमस्थानाद् द्वितीयं बलवत्तरम् । तयोरीशौ
> तत्र गताः पापिनस्तेन संयुताः ॥ ३॥ ये खेटाः पापिनस्ते च सर्वे
> मारकसंज्ञकाः । तेषां दशाविपाकेषु सम्भवे निधनं नृणाम् ॥ ४॥
> अल्पमध्यमपूर्णायुः प्रमाणमिह योगजम् । विज्ञाय प्रथमं पुंसां मारकं
> परिचिन्तयेत् ॥ ५॥
>
> > - 2. O Brahmin, the 3rd and 8th are the two houses of longevity. The houses related to death are the 12th from each of these, i.e. the 2nd
> >      and 7th are Maraka houses.
>
> <sup>**Notes:** The 3rd house is also a house of longevity as it is
> the 8th from the 8th. The 2nd house — 12ih from the 3rd— and the 7th
> house — 12th from the 8th — are two principle Maraka houses. The lords
> of these houses will also acquire such qualities giving life or taking
> away life.</sup>
>
> > - 3 to 5. Out of the two (i.e 2nd and 7th) the 2nd is a powerful Maraka house (as against the 7th) The lords of the 2nd and the 7th, malefics
> >   in the 2nd and the 7th and malefics accompanying the 2nd and the 7th
> >   lords are all known as Marakas. The major and sub periods of these
> >   planets will bring death on the native depending on whether he has a
> >   long life, medium life or short life.
>
> <sup>**Notes:** The 2nd and 7th are denoted as Maraka houses. But the
> 2nd is given a more important place to kill than the 7th house. For
> the 2nd house acquires an additional qualification of being in the 7th
> from the 8th house. Thus, the 2nd is 12th from the 3rd, and 7th from
> the 8th. If there is a malefic in the 2nd or in the 7th, he will be a
> prime killer while a benefic will not be so. The Dasa periods of such
> planets will inflict death.</sup>
>
> ---
>
> अलाभे पुनरेतेषां सम्बन्धेन व्ययेशितुः । क्वचिच्छुभानां च
> दशस्वष्टमेशदशासु च ॥ ६॥ केवलानां च पापानां दशासु निधनं क्वचित् ।
> अल्पनीयं बुधैर्नृणां मारकाणामदर्शने ॥ ७॥ सत्यपि स्वेन सम्बन्धे न हन्ति
> शुभभुक्तिषु । हन्ति सत्यप्यसम्बन्धे मारकः पापभुक्तिषु ॥ ८॥
>
> > - 6 to 7. The Dasa of a benefic planet related to the 12th lord may also inflict death. End may descend on the native in the 8th lord’s Dasa.
> >   The Dasa of a planet which is an exclusive malefic (i.e. first-rate
> >   malefic) may also cause death.
>
> <sup>**Notes:** The 12th house is also a house of death, for it is the
> terminal house. Malefics related to 2nd, 3rd, 7th and 8th will cause
> death while or not a benefic related to 12th will do so. The Dasa of a
> malefic, whether or not he is a lord of one of these houses, will also
> prove harmful for span of life. However, for Saturn, a different
> approach is recommended.</sup>

#### To Sumarize:

- 'Māraka' means killer. There are certain planets (*graha*) in certain houses of the horoscope which are said to be able to either kill a person when in the *daśā* period, or either inflict an agony equivalent to death on the native. Under such conditions, the Native is said to be experiencing the Māraka daśā of the Māraka planet.
- Also, the translator, Dr. R. Santhanam, notes that -

> "The rules given are just general and are hints to decide death
> givers. The life span should be ascertained through other Ayurdaya
> calculations, and the exact dasa periods be decided only later on.
> Simply saying that the 2nd lord’s dasa will bring in death and so on
> and so forth will be a misnomer"
>
> .....
>
> "**A difficult subject like longevity cannot be fully explained in a
> chapter like this. The reader may take basic guidelines from the
> present work and other standard works before forming an opinion on
> longevity.**"

---

`Question 2 - Does any canonical text dwell on the perfect inflicting nature of either a Saturn's or Guru's Māraka daśā?`

- **Yes,** as per the Brihat-Parashara Hora Shastra, out of all planets, the impact of Saturn is said to be most impeccable.

> मारकग्रहसम्बन्धान्निहन्ता पापकृच्छनिः । अतिक्रम्येतरान् सर्वान्
> भवत्यत्र न संशयः ॥ ४४.९ ॥
>
> > 9. **Should Saturn be ill-disposed and be related to a Maraka Planet, he will be the first to kill in preference to other Planets.**
>
> English translation by Dr. R. Santhanam